# How to create break a loop on every third object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add a class to the first three database objects, then another class for the 4 to 6 objects and so on...

I found ways to break the loop but I hope there are better ways to accomplish bunches of three than to have to hardcode a lot of loops?

I'm thankful for all help!

http://jsfiddle.net/r61bce3z/

this is the basics of the loop i have:

```
var tableContent = '';

$.getJSON( '/users/insights', function( data ) {
userListData = data;
$.each(data, function(){
    tableContent += '<ul>';
    tableContent += '<li class="sub">' + this.date + '</li>';
    tableContent += '</ul>';
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure you need to break out of the loop. You could use the first parameter passed to your callback (the index of the current item in the loop), and find out if it `% 3` to change a variable to use to set the class

Comment: It's not modulus but `Math.floor()` is needed in this case.

Comment: @zerkms I'm not sure I follow - can you explain?

Comment: @Ian: with `% 3` you'd pick `0, 3, 6` whereas op needs `0..2`, `3..5`, etc

Comment: Put a list of class names in an array, then have a counter variable to tell you which name you're up to.

Comment: @zerkms My point was that you could have a separate variable, say `className` be set. Then, on each iteration, you check for `% 3 === 0`. If that's true, you're on a new set of 3 and you would change the value of `className`. Isn't that right? I'm sure either solution works depending on how you use it. Maybe yours is easier, I'm not sure (I'm still not sure how you'd use `Math.floor()` but that's probably just my ignorance)

Comment: @Ian: "a class to the first three database objects, then another class for the 4 to 6 objects" --- assuming you have `i` index show how would you put `1..3` into one group and `4..6` into another using modulus operator.

Comment: it sounds exactly what i want do to, but i still have som problems with how i use the parameter... can you please write it so I can follow what you mean?

Comment: @zerkms Is this not it? http://jsfiddle.net/ko987m0g/

Comment: @Ian: it is. But instead of using a free variable you could use `Math.floor(i / 3)` which is side-effect free

Comment: @zerkms Ooooohhh okay, I didn't realize that's what you meant. I thought you meant using `%` in the logic wouldn't work (I thought maybe I read the question wrong and didn't understand the point even). I definitely see your point of solving it without the extra variable. Anyways, the `%` was just my initial thought (which was obviously inferior)

Comment: @Ian - I think you want `Math.floor()` _and_ `%` in the logic, in case there are more groups of three than classes. (As shown in my answer.)

Comment: @nnnnnn Yeah, definitely. Again, the `%` was my initial thought, and your answer is definitely improved

Answer (score 3):

The `$.each()` method calls your function with an index for the element it is up to. So use that with a little arithmetic as an index into an array of class names:

```
var classes = ['class1', 'class2', 'class3', 'class4'];

$.getJSON( '/users/insights', function( data ) {
    userListData = data;
    $.each(data, function(i){
        tableContent += '<ul>';
        tableContent += '<li class="' + classes[Math.floor(i/3) % classes.length]
                        + '">' + this.date + '</li>';
        tableContent += '</ul>';
    });
});
```

Using `Math.floor(i/3)` gives you your groups of 3. Adding in `% classes.length` allows for if you have more groups of 3 than classes (so that you don't go past the end of the array of classes, it'll just start reusing the classes from the beginning of the array).

Comment: amazing! is there anyway were I dont have to put the classes in a array but just +1 or something, so the class applied changes and not pick the next one,

Comment: like var class = 'class' + 1

Comment: and after three object +1 more is added

Comment: You can say `var className = 'class' + Math.floor(i/3);`

Answer (score 0):

You can make it with some helper variables.

```
var tableContent = '';
var classIndex=-1;

$.getJSON( '/users/insights', function( data ) {
    userListData = data;
    $.each(data, function(index){
        if(index % 3 == 0) classIndex++;
        var css = classes[classIndex];
        tableContent += '<ul>';
        tableContent += '<li class="myClass' + classIndex + '">' + this.date + '</li>';
        tableContent += '</ul>';
    });
}
```

Comment: You forgot to modify `i`